# How To Sort Cloned Div's in Droppable Div

Tags: html, jquery-ui

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5DF/5/) where I have 2 divs.

```
<div>
    <div class="inner1" id="sortable">
        <div class="inner" id="a"> a </div>
        <div class="inner"> b</div>
        <div class="inner"> c</div>
        <div class="inner"> d</div>
    </div>
    <div class="inner1" id="draggable"> -----&gt; </div>
    <div class="inner1" id="droppable">

    </div>
</div>
```

1st Div have items a,b,c,d which are Sortable and 2nd Div is Droppable.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert:true
    });
    $("#draggable").parent().draggable();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop:function(e,ui){
           if($(ui.draggable).parent().attr("id")!=$(this).attr("id"))
            $(ui.draggable).clone().appendTo($(this));
        },
        revert:true
    });
     $("#droppable").sortable();
});
```

If the items are Dropped from Div1 to Div2 , they are cloned. This much is happening.

But i need them to be Sortable in 2nd Div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's alredy sortable try just remove style atribute after drop: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7f5DF/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sortable").sortable({
        revert:true
    });
    $("#draggable").parent().draggable();
    $("#droppable").droppable({
        drop:function(e,ui){
            if($(ui.draggable).parent().attr("id")!=$(this).attr("id")){
               var clone = $(ui.draggable).clone();
                clone.removeAttr("style");
                clone.appendTo($(this));
            }
        },
        revert:true
    });
     $("#droppable").sortable();
});
```

here works fine for me :D